# Difference between UIElementCollection and Collection<UIElement>?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, collections, uielement

In WPF and Silverlight, we have seen the following classes:

- `UIElementCollection`
- `ItemCollection`
- `RowDefinitionCollection`
- `ColumnDefinitionCollection`
- `PointCollection`
- and a lot more....

Why do they have these classes, one class for each type? Why did they not use generic classes such as `Collection<T>`?

Also, I've seen in Silverlight, all of these classes have been derived from `PresentationFrameworkCollection<T>` , as

```
public sealed class ItemCollection : PresentationFrameworkCollection<Object> 
public sealed class PointCollection : PresentationFrameworkCollection<Object> 
public sealed class IconCollection : PresentationFrameworkCollection<Object> 
//and so on...
```

If all of these derive from a common class, and I don't see anything public in the derived classes (all of them are empty!), then why did they define them in the first place? I feel that there are some differences which are either declared `private` or `internal` in the derived classes. But I don't exactly know.

Please help me understanding the design of these classes. In particular, why did they use them instead of generic classes which come with the framework? What are the benefits?

Comment: That's like saying what's the difference between a car manufacturing plant and a junkyard - they both manage a collection car parts.

Comment: What's the difference between a swiss-army knife and a toolbox?

Comment: @Alain: Your comments didn't help me in any way. I'm still ignorant.

Comment: I'm alluding to the fact that having a generic collection of things is not always useful, it takes an enhanced class to perform special operations on those things and organize them in a way that makes sense only for those things - features which a generic collection class can't provide.

Comment: @Alain: I can guess that. But I'm still ignorant. What "special operations" are you talking about? I'm looking for some concrete knowledge. :-)

Comment: As an example, collections that deal with Interface elements handle UI-specific needs such as setting up event handlers, determining when the child elements need to be refreshed, performing clones without crossing event-handler wires, etc. Best way to see it just to look at the msdn class description for each and see how much they differ, eg: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcollection.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They internally work different, based on the use case they were designed for. For example, `UIElementCollection` doesn't just hold the elements, but also makes sure they are added and removed from the corresponding visual tree...

Comment: In addition, the main difference between them and a simple Collection<T>, is that they inherit from DependencyObject

Comment: This depends. In WPF this is not the case.